How to connect external FTP server in Azure Data Factory?
The "FtpFiledToConnectToFtpServer" error occurred when tried to create a linked service which connect to external FTP server.

This Azure is company's environment and using private network in Azure.
I'm not familiar with network settings in Azure(Managed Virtual Network, NSG, NIC etc...).
So I have no idea what should I do to connect external FTP server.
The server information in the attached image is correct because I can connect with the information using WinSCP.
The FTP server I am trying to connect to does not have a firewall restricting connections from the outside.
Considering this, I guess the network setting causes this issue.
Is there anybody can resolve it?
The current settings are described below.
1.Data Factory Networking Setting
using a “Private endpoint connection”, which is tied to an NSG that is allowed to connect to the FTP server.


2.Using "Integration Runtime(Managed Virtual Network)" in the linked service.

Any answer would be helped.
Thank you.


Failed to connect to FTP server. Please make sure the provided server information is correct

In your case issue may be with Integration Runtime or ftp server credentials. You are using managed Vnet IR. Make sure you have followed the instructions in the MS document while creating managed Vnet IR.
Otherwise, if your ftp server is located inside an on-premises network, an Azure virtual network, or Amazon Virtual Private Cloud, you need to configure a self-hosted integration runtime to connect to it.
Try to configure linked service as shown below:

Make sure you have given correct details and credentials of ftp server  and for more information you can refer to this MS Document.
